# DB2 Grouping and Orderby

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

I need the to order results by `PUNCH_TS` but retain the grouping of `TYPE_CD`.

Query:

```
select TYPE_CD, PUNCH_TS 
from PUNCH
group by PUNCH_TS, TYPE_CD 
order by TYPE_CD, PUNCH_TS asc
```

Result:

```
ADM 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
ADM 2020-01-13 17:00:00.0
REG 2020-01-13 08:00:00.0
REG 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
```

I changed the order by from the `TYPE_CD` to `PUNCH_TS` but then it loses the grouping of `TYPE_CD`:

```
REG 2020-01-13 08:00:00.0
ADM 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
REG 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
ADM 2020-01-13 17:00:00.0
```

What I need is:

```
REG 2020-01-13 08:00:00.0
REG 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
ADM 2020-01-13 12:00:00.0
ADM 2020-01-13 17:00:00.0
```

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are involved? Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
order by TYPE_CD desc, PUNCH_TS
```

Rationale: if you want `TYPE_CD` `'REG'` to appear before `'ADM'`, then you need to a descending sort. The second sort criteria is ascending `PUNCH_TS`, so you get results ordered by ascending timestamp within groups having the same `TYPE_CD`.

---

**Edit**

If you want the `TYPE_CD` that has the earlier timestamp first, then you can use window functions:

```
order by min(PUNCH_TS) over(partition by TYPE_CD), PUNCH_TS
```

Comment: @ZacharyLoughridge: I think that your second example corresponds to `ORDER BY PUNCH_TS, TYPE_CD`.

Comment: Works for this example only. Say the times were swapped, i would need the ADM to be first @GMB

Comment: @ZacharyLoughridge: OK I think I see what you mean. Answer updated.

Comment: Perfect just ran it through a few of my real scenarios. Thanks marking this answered